# How to get the first column of an excel file using VBA present in VISIO

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I have a Visio file in which I wrote VBA code. Earlier I was giving input manually. Now I want to give the input using an excel file. The input is present in the first column of the excel file. The following code is not giving the desired result.

```
Sub OpenSaveExcel()

    Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLBook As Object
    Dim strArray As Variant
    Dim TotalRows As Long

    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("File location")
    Dim x As Variant

    x = objXLBook.Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    Debug.Print x(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to use `Worksheets` method to access the worksheet? The "shorthand" syntax you showed may be working inside of Excel but not outside (not sure). Anyways, this should work I hope:

```
x = objXLBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
```